# How can I get my javascript function randomly select one function(slideshow), execute it, then repeat?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, random, onload

I have a javascript code for replacing a html `<div>` that contains an image in it, so it becomes like a slide show.  I have six of these slideshows on the page, and I need them to randomly change maybe switch image 3 then 6 then 2 and ect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     SlideShow6();
});

function SlideShow6() {
    $('#slideshow6 > div:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow6 > div:first')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(0)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow6');
    }, 0000);
}
```

The time over here at the end is `0000` (0)seconds.  Becuase I need the timer to have a `2000` (2)second pause before picking a random slide to slide.  I tried my script with this:

```
var funcs = [];

funcs[0] = function() {
    $('#slideshow6 > div:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow6 > div:first')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(0)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow6');
    }, 0000);
}
funcs[1] = function() {
    $('#slideshow5 > div:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow5 > div:first')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(0)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow5');
    }, 0000);
}
```

// and so on six times...
then...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rand = parseInt(Math.random()*funcs.length);  
    funcs[rand]();
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);
});
```

It becomes really weird, it selects my functions randomly but it executes the slideshow a unlimited number of times and before soon all six of them are on and going.  Maybe because of the `0000`?  I need them to switch image one by one.

**----------UPDATE----------**
I'm not sure if it was understandable from the code above but the `SlideShow6` function repeats 6 times with a different `funcs[1]` number every time so that it can add slideshows for all 6 images into the `funcs[]` array.

I am a newbie to JavaScript but in words this is how I image the code:

Need to make an array so I put all these functions into into it

```
var funcs = [];
funcs[0] = function() {
    $('#slideshow1 > div:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow1 > div:first')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(0)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow1');
    }, 0000);    
}
funcs[1] = function() {
**All the same except number slideshow1 changes to 2,3,4,5, and 6**
}
funcs[2] = function() {
}
funcs[3] = function() {
}
funcs[4] = function() {
}
funcs[5] = function() {
}
```

Then you need to call it up so make a math function that chooses 1-6 randomly which ever number is chosen then that functions is played out once.  Then the randomize pick another number in 2 seconds. And another image slide changes.  That's all it is every 2 seconds forever. Thanks.

Comment: `0000` in `setTimeout` is saying "wait 0 milliseconds" aka don't wait. Might as well skip the `setTimeout` calls if you have a value of 0.

Comment: Hey @MatthewHerbst How can I cancel it? If I try removing the `0000` then it wont work at all.  But I don't want to remove the `2000` I want it to randomly switch an image every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All testing done in Chrome console:

Setting the second parameter of `setInterval` to `0` causes the function to be run an unlimited number of time. I don't know why - I would expect the function to simply run a single time immediately.

You can see this in your console by doing:

```
setInterval(function () {
  console.log('Crazy');
}, 0000);
```

---

(There was a few iterations of this post which I have removed for brevity since they were deemed non-sufficient by question OP.)

---

**Update 2:**

```
var funcs = [];

funcs[0] = function() {
  $('#slideshow6 > div:gt(0)').hide();

  $('#slideshow6 > div:first')
    .fadeOut(0)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(0)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow6');
}

funcs[1] = ...;
funcs[2] = ...;
funcs[3] = ...;
funcs[4] = ...;
funcs[5] = ...;

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.setInterval(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * funcs.length);
    funcs[rand]();
  }, 2000);
});
```

I think this is a much more elegant solution. What this does: loop forever. Every loop iteration, wait 2 seconds and then switch a random image.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Herbst but it won't exactly work like I wanted. It does select a random one but then every 2 seconds it slides just that one.  I would like it to select a random one every 2 seconds and slide it once. But thanks anyway this is closer than I ever got on my own.  I would appreciative if you could update your answer. Thanks Again.

Comment: Every two seconds forever you mean?

Comment: @user3263981 check out the update I just made. I think it will be what you're looking for.

Comment: Unlike your first code, the second one didn't work at all. Please see my update.

Comment: @Sammy7 I'm not sure your update clears things up for me, sorry. What about the new code I wrote doesn't work for you? My understanding of what you want is: there are 6 images on the page, every 2 seconds you want a random number of them to change. Which part of that is incorrect or what am I missing?

Comment: yes that is correct, six images every 2 seconds a random one changes.  And no your second code did not work.  But also I can't understand why you added in `random image every 0 - 2 seconds` and `number of images to change` it's always going to be 1 image changing every 2 seconds. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Sammy7 I'll update based on above when I get back from work tonight. Keep your rep and just mark answer as correct once we've figured it out. Learning all around here which is what the site is really about! :)

Comment: @Sammy7 look at the updated code in the answer. It will do what you've asked for in the previous comment.

Comment: The code looks great, but I can't even test it, it just starts freezing up my browser and asking me to `stop script` or `debug script`

Comment: @Sammy7 AH! I wasn't thinking straight late last night. Infinite loops crash browsers! Look at the updated code (again). It will run forever every 2 seconds without crashing the browser or causing a StackOverflow.

Comment: Works like a charm, how can I hide all the `$('#slideshow6 > div:gt(0)').hide()` slideshow's second images on page load? So then they can switch out? Thanks.